Getting message "Sequence contains more than one element"
I am running Json script to transfer test plan and was getting this error. How to resolve or debug this.
"Sequence contains more than one element"

    {
"ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
"Source": {
"$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
"Collection": "http://alpvbhnptfsa01.ent.bhicorp.com:8080/tfs/XXX/",
"Project": "XXXXX",
"ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild",
"AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
"AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
"PersonalAccessToken": "",
"PersonalAccessTokenVariableName": "",
"LanguageMaps": {
"AreaPath": "Area",
"IterationPath": "Iteration"
}
},
"Target": {
"$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
"Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/XXXXXXXX/",
"Project": "XXXXXXXXXX",
"ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
"AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
"AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
"PersonalAccessToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"PersonalAccessTokenVariableName": "",
"LanguageMaps": {
"AreaPath": "Area",
"IterationPath": "Iteration"
}
},
"FieldMaps": [
{
"$type": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
"WorkItemTypeName": "*",
"sourceFieldsAndValues": { "System.State": "New" },
"targetFieldsAndValues": { "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate": null, "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy": null, "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate":null, "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy": null}
}
],
"GitRepoMapping": null,
"LogLevel": "Debug",
"CommonEnrichersConfig": null,
"Processors": [
{
"$type": "TestVariablesMigrationConfig",
"Enabled": true
},
{
"$type": "TestConfigurationsMigrationConfig",
"Enabled": true
},
{
"$type": "TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationConfig",
"Enabled": true,
"PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
"OnlyElementsWithTag": null,
"TestPlanQueryBit": null,
"RemoveAllLinks": false,
"MigrationDelay": 0,
"UseCommonNodeStructureEnricherConfig": false,
"NodeBasePaths": [],
"AreaMaps": null,
"IterationMaps": {},
"RemoveInvalidTestSuiteLinks": false,
"FilterCompleted": false
}
],
"Version": "14.4",
"workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
"WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
"sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
},
"Endpoints": {
"InMemoryWorkItemEndpoints": [
{
"Name": "Source",
"EndpointEnrichers": null
},
{
"Name": "Target",
"EndpointEnrichers": null
}
]
}
}   


Can you share more details about the error message? The current error message is vague, it should contain more information

I have check the configuration.json file and it should be correct.

"Sequence contains more than one element"

I encountered the same issue when the target project already has the test plans, test suites and test cases with the same name as the ones being migrated.

To solve this issue, you need to query all Test Plans, Test Suites and Test Cases in the source and target projects, and then you can check if there are work item titles with the same name.
If yes, you need to change the title of the test work items in Source or Target Projects. Then you can re-run the migration command to migrate the test work items.
You need to ensure that the title of the migrated test work items are unique.
Refer to the answer of the Migration tool developer: Issue in TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationConfig of Azure DevOps Migration Tools
